# Is CloudFront deleting Server-Timing header added by Lambda@Edge?

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge, server-timing

I've got a **Viewer Response** Lambda@Edge script that adds a Server-Timing header manually by reading other information from headers. This way, my JavaScript code can read this value and use it for other client-side functionality such as reporting.

```
export async function viewerResponse(event) {
  const { request, response } = event.Records[0].cf;
  response.headers['Server-Timing'] = [{ key: 'Server-Timing', value: 'something' }];
  return response;
}
```

So far so good. I can see the header being added at the edge.

However, when CloudFront registers a HIT (as seen by the header `X-Cache: hit by cloudfront`), the Server-Timing header mysteriously vanishes. It is as if CloudFront decides to override this header.

Has anyone seen anything like this? Can CloudFront be told to stop interfering?

I have tried to enable Server-Timing in CloudFront's security headers policy. This added CloudFront's own Server-Timing variables in addition to the custom stuff I wanted for any cache miss. But as soon as a cache hit occurs, the custom additions get removed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling the 'Server-Timing' header in your response CachePolicy in CloudFront?

[image]